# Simplifying Simplify[Conjugate[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]], {a < b}]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

How can one simplify the following

```
 Simplify[Conjugate[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]], {a < b}]
```

Edit: I want to add that in my case $a$ and $b$ are real and I expect Mathematica to return $-i\sqrt{b^2-a^2}$.

Comment: What simplification do you expect? $ \left\{\begin{array}{ll}-i\sqrt{b^2-a^2}& \text{if } |a|<|b|,\\ \sqrt{a^2-b^2} & \text{else}\end{array}\right.$?

Comment: Try `FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], a < b]` and report back.

Comment: I expect Mathematica to return $i\sqrt{b^2-a^2}$given  $a$ and $b$ are real.

Comment: If `b==1` and `a==0` then $i\ \sqrt{b^2-a^2}=i$ which is different from `Conjugate[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]]==-I`

Comment: Sorry I meant $-i\sqrt{(b^2 - a^2)}$.

Answer (score 3):

A slight modification of @J.M.'s ennui's comment:

```
FullSimplify[
    ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[a^2-b^2]],TargetFunctions->{Re,Im}],
    -b<a<b
]
```

> -I Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2]

Comment: Yes, this looks way better than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sl = Solve[a^2 - b^2 == -x^2, b][[2, 1]]

(*  b -> Sqrt[a^2 + x^2]  *)

Simplify[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] /. sl, x > 0] /. x -> Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2]

(* I Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2]  *)
```

Have fun!